# Redirecionar domínio para determinada pasta do servidor via htaccess

Tags: regex, htaccess, redirecionamento, domínio

Tenho dois domínios que apontam para meu servidor, ambos para a pasta raiz public_html. Preciso que cada domínio acesse determinada pasta.

Exemplo:

www.dominio1.com.br aponta para a pasta /dominio_1

www.dominio2.com.br aponta para a pasta /dominio_2

Procurei os comandos para utilizar no htaccess mas sem sucesso. Não entendo muito de expressão regular, alguém aí tem as manhas?

Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para realizar esta tarefa é necessário utilizar o [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*dominio1.* [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dominio1.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*dominio2.* [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dominio2.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

#### Explicação

- `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` - Diz que você que verificar algo no domínio
- `.*dominio1.*` - Esta verificando se o domínio possui a sentença
- `[NC]` - No case - Quer disser que é case insensitive.

Se a sentença for confirmada, similar a um `if` realiza o `RewriteRule` que esta abaixo.